# pass variable to coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

from command line, how to pass a variable to coffeescript, so it can replace a corresponding placeholder, something like this:

```
$ echo "module.exports = {version: '$VERSION'}" | coffee -p -s VERSION=0.0.0
```

Expected JS:

```
(function() {

  module.exports = {
    version: '0.0.0'
  };

}).call(this);
```

Thank you

Comment: CoffeeScript alone won't do this for you.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695207/conditional-compilation-in-coffeescript-uglifyjs/9703921) has some discussion of preprocessors that could run either before or after `coffee`.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

- You need to define `VERSION` in the echo, not in the coffeescript compiler; by the time the coffeescript compiler sees it it's already translated `$VERSION` into `''`.
- `echo` is a shell builtin, and therefore the standard `VERSION=0.0.0 echo "$VERSION"` construct doesn't work.

So you want to create a new subshell so that the setting of VERSION doesn't propagate into your main shell, then perform the echo and coffee, like so:

```
$ (VERSION=0.0.0; echo "module.exports = {version: '$VERSION'}" | coffee -ps)       
(function() {

  module.exports = {
    version: '0.0.0'
  };

}).call(this);
```

The parentheses around the expression stop VERSION from being set:

```
$ echo $VERSION                                                              

$
```

Comment: Ok, my example is probably too simple... Your trick works well but it's rather a shell rather a coffee one. What if I want to compile a whole folder: `coffee -c -o lib/ src/` but with `VERSION=0.0.0` so `$VERSION` placeholder is replaced somewhere in `src/`? Thanks